# How to remove duplicate shortcut folders without erasing originals?

Tags: google-drive

We are sharing a google drive folder in the office, somebody moved the primary folder and somehow became the owner of it and all it's contents. When transferring ownership of the folder and subfolders back to me, both the main folder and subfolders appeared in the root of my drive:

```
> Folder > Subfolder 1
         > Subfolder 2
> Subfolder 1
> Subfolder 2
```

I want to remove the duplicate subfolders from the root, but if I do they instantly disappear from the main folder. I have tried everything but I can't understand how to delete the duplicates.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Best answer here... Thank you so much for posting this. It was driving me crazy. I just clicked on the folder and under details, it shows all the "locations" and each location has an "**X**" next to it. You can remove it from any of the "locations" on this screen. See my screenshot:

[image: Drive Details Snapshot]

Comment: Wow, so unintuitive and confusing from Google - thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

My solution: 
(works only "old google drive interface")

1. Open Google Drive in the browser
2. Click on MyDrive
3. On the right panel (!!), click on the checkbox, next to "*> Subfolder 1*" (that is in the root folder)
4. Right-click, and select MOVE
5. Move it to **> Folder > Subfolder 1** (don't worry that "*> Folder*" is checked in the pop-up)
6. That's all.

The shortcut in the root will disappear but the folder and its content is feeling well in the "*> Folder > Subfolder 1*" folder.